# View Stackify Prefix for all IIS sites

Tags: stackify

I'm running Stackify Prefix (v2.5.19) and a bunch of (IIS hosted) micro services on my local machine.

SP seems to only show events from some of the applications in the browser. However, when I examine `C:\Program Files (x86)\StackifyPrefix\profiles\`, I can see paths corresponding to the process id's of the other services, and the expected data is in the profile0.log file.

How do I get SP to display this data for all of my applications in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix for non-web apps takes some additional work to do.  The problem is that Prefix doesn't know how to define the start and end of a transaction natively.  There are some things that we do automatically figure out and we are building more support for known non-iis transactions but the best method is to instrument those yourself.

Here is a guide to how to do it.

http://support.stackify.com/hc/en-us/articles/210565263-How-to-use-Prefix-with-non-IIS-NET-applications